# Set Location of ListView below DataGridView Active Row in C# Winform

Tags: c#, mysql, listview, datagridview

Tools:
Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, 
Language C#,
Database MySql

Hi,

I am searching this a while, but to date didn't find any suitable solution.

I've a form with bound DataGridView with 5 columns, ProductID, ProductName, Qty, Price and Amount. After normal data entry user can click button to save data to Mysql database, no problem there.

At present user is manually enter ProductID after which an Sql command is executed to fetch ProductName and sets it to DataGridView ProductName Column. I need a way to show a ListView below ProductID column when it got focus, so that user can select product (ProductID and ProductName) from ListView and set it to DataGridView's Row which user is currently using.

Is it possible to show listview below ProductID cell when user click or when got focus?

Thanks

Ahmed

Comment: @GrantWinney any suggestion/link for ListView?

Comment: @Ahmed you can't. DataGridView does not support ListView column. What you can do is manually create and locate the ListView control on the position where to row is located. But you will then have to treat cases such as scrolling.

Comment: @etaiso this is exactly what I am looking for...How to locate the position where the current row is located and make ListView below it???

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, I think it's a good start - but definitely need improvements. But please not that as I mentioned in my comment above, you should treat special cases such as scrolling or even expanding the grid so the `ListView` will not hide `DataGridView` rows.

On your `DataGridView` subscribe the `MouseMove` event and store the mouse location:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseLoc = e.Location;
}
```

You can set `mouseLoc` as a property.

`private Point mouseLoc = new Point();`

And also subscribe to `CellMouseDown` event, with this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Location = new Point(mouseLoc.X, mouseLoc.Y + dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Size.Height);
    listView1.BringToFront();
    listView1.Refresh();
}
```